# Add marker to google map with socket.io and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, socket.io

I am new & beginner in socket.io 
I can emit events with socket & node.js
now I want to get an array with the lat , lang from the user & then 
set the marker on the google map dynamically

here is my code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="map" style="width:;height:700px;background:yellow"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng('23.11', '71.00'),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCm2vXXUTO627j8UHqDIKvvETwuNT1dqxQ&callback=myMap"></script>

    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        //I want to add marker here
        });
      });
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can see my event an d google maps scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple for a good start:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:;height:700px;background:yellow"></div>
    <script>
      function myMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng('23.11', '71.00'),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      }
   </script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCm2vXXUTO627j8UHqDIKvvETwuNT1dqxQ&callback=myMap"></script>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng('23.11', '71.00'),
            title: msg,
            label: 'a',
            map: map
           });
           marker.setMap(map);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in the server you only need this:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    socket.emit ('chat message', msg);   
});
```

You will have to add some bells and whistles like sending your position, username, marker icons etc.